# Dynamics crm retrieveEntityReq (Javascript) function in c# [OnPrem CRM]

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have a query.
In Javascript, I have code as below i.e I am using retrieveEntityReq for getting data for “Executing Report“ using POST Request.
I want to achieve the same with C#, If I have googled correctly I guess we have in c# “RetrieveEntityRequest“ function. This function helps us retrieve Metadata from System.
But is it possible to achieve something like executing report and getting the response from the report?

Additional Comment: What is my End goal here:
The code mentioned above is to render report and then get report data in base64 String. Once I have it in bas64  attach it as pdf in Email.
All this is already achieved in JavaScript (base64 string) and plugin for crating email and attaching pdf.
Now I wish to achieve base64 string of a SSRS report in c#.

Few more googling gave me insight of [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) which helps to achieve similar request i.e GET/POST and so on.
I tried using it, I do get status as OK but the content is not available. Maybe this helps to clarify my question more.

```
var retrieveEntityReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

retrieveEntityReq.open("POST", pth, false);

retrieveEntityReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");

retrieveEntityReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

//This statement runs the query and executes the report synchronously.

retrieveEntityReq.send(query);

//These variables captures the response and returns the response in an array.

var x = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.lastIndexOf("ReportSession=");

var y = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.lastIndexOf("ControlID=");
```

Update: I could not achieve rendering report same as using Javascript.
Different approach used is: Publishing report on Server and then rendering it using c# code.

Reference link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675762/Call-SSRS-Reports-by-using-Csharp

Comment: This is intended for running report on client side, Why do you want do this in server side c# ?

Comment: What sort of report do you want to run?

Comment: Yes the code mentioned helps to achieve render report using Js (clientside).
The report I wish to run is SSRS report

Comment: Don’t add answer as an edit to the question, instead post it as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of clarifications: SDK exposed `RetrieveEntityRequest` message is for querying Metadata about Entity. Whereas `retrieveEntityReq` in your code sample is just a **variable** to execute ajax request using `XMLHttpRequest`. [This executes/run a SSRS report](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/205829) & gets response like session, etc.

If you really want to query the data similar to SSRS report in server side using C#, we have [FetchExpression](https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/retrieve-records-using-fetchxml-c-sdk-in-crm/) concept to run the fetchxml query (same as SSRS report query) & get the response.